# WHEN Matched with INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which works fine but updates the existing row whereas can I have it to INSERT a new row:

```
create procedure [Adm].[Proc_Reports]
(
    @TestID bigint,
    @AgentID bigint,
    @AcctMonth bigint
)
as
begin
    set nocount on
    ;merge into [Adm].[Reports]  as Target
    using (select @TestID, @AgentID, @AcctMonth) as Source (TestID, AgentID, AcctMonth)
    on Target.TestID=Source.TestID
        and Target.AgentID=Source.AgentID
        and Target.AcctMonth=Source.AcctMonth
    when matched then update set UploadCount += 1
    when not matched then
        insert (TestID, AgentID, AcctMonth, UploadCount)
        values (TestID, AgentID, AcctMonth, 1);
end
go
```

Comment: The `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clause looks to me like it inserts a new row when the specified TestID,AgentID, and AcctMonth doesn't exist in the target table. Is it not working as expected?

Comment: `;` is a statement terminator, not a "beginningator". It goes after your `SET NOCOUNT ON;` not before a `MERGE`/`WITH`.

Comment: Basically WHEN MATCHED then INSERT a new row which sets the UploadCount to +1 but when NOT MATCHED INSERT a new row. I hope I am making sense and please advise

Comment: Doing something like `SET UoloadCount = UploadCount +1` is actually a bad idea; if you have 2 updates running at the same time you could very well end up with race conditions and end up with the wrong results. A "Count" should be a calculated value, by performing a `COUNT` of the related rows in the (other?) table.

Comment: @Kash You can insert a row in the WHEN MATCHED section. You can say WHEN MATCHED INSERT instead of WHEN MATCHED UPDATE.

Comment: @NeerajAgarwal I tried to replace the UPDATE to INSERT but loosing the syntax as I have to SET the value and INSERT?

Comment: @Larnu Can you please elaborate a little more

Comment: I *assume* you have a uploads table; so instead of incrementing the value of uploads by the user, you count the rows the user has in the uploads table.

Comment: @Larnu oh ok let me try and if you can modify the above code then that would be a big help

Comment: @Kash I was incorrect. MERGE will not allow you to insert WHEN MATCHED. You have to do that in a separate SQL statement.

Comment: Consider [Bugs with MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Comment: @DanGuzman Do you have an alternative solution instead of using the MERGE for this scenario - thank you

Comment: @Kash, I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to accomplish. Is it that you want to always insert a new row with the `UploadCount` being the total of uploads for the key combination thus far? My first inclination would be to add an IDENTITY column to the table (e.g. `UploadSequence`), drop the UploadCount column, and calculate the running total in `SELECT` queries using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY (TestID, AgentID, AcctMonth) ORDER BY (UploadSequence) AS UploadCount`. Then the proc code would only need an unconditional `INSERT`.

Comment: @DanGuzman thank you for explaining in detail